# Can't localize Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges description

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, localization, international-sites

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

> [image]

- Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.
- Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses.
- Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.

The are those strings in Transifex:

- `e73a95c2fd31ac263d0a2536b4ed7667`.
- `9ef3aaa56f815660ae1108e64c875692`.
- `9d95be52708a183867b6c0254d4e717f`.

And they were translated years ago. But right now those badges aren't translated. And I can't find new strings in transifex.

Have you changed something recently? Could you fix it?

Comment: The descriptions *were* recently changed to say "post" instead of "question" while fixing a bug, which explains the need to be retranslated. Guess someone forgot to add the new ones.

Comment: @animuson so...could you add them? )

Comment: This was tagged as completed; since this doesn't result in a notification, posting this comment to let you know.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, but I've seen info about tag changes on my profile page (: